# How to write a Junit test of Excel Upload?

Tags: java, excel, testing, junit, apache-poi

guys.I'm a beginner learning java.And now i have to write a Junit test of Excel upload function in my company demo project.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/excelImport")
public ModelAndView excelImport(@RequestParam(value = "filename")MultipartFile file,
        ModelAndView mav) {
    session.setAttribute("imported",false);//セッションのインポート記録をリセットして、次の操作を影響しないように
    List<RetirementPayAndHealthInsurance> errorList= new ArrayList<>();//エラーデータリスト
    List<RetirementPayAndHealthInsurance> importList = new ArrayList<>();//導入されたデータリスト
    int wnt = 0;//エラー数
    int cnt = 0;//正常数
    String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
    if(file.isEmpty()) {    //ファイル選択なしにインポートボタンを押す場合
        mav.setViewName("redirect:/retailList");
        return mav;
    }else {

        try {
            Map<String,List<RetirementPayAndHealthInsurance>> map = retirementPayAndHealthInsuranceService.batchImport(fileName, file);
            errorList = map.get("errorList");
            importList = map.get("importList");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO 自動生成された catch ブロック
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(errorList!=null) {//エラーリストあるの場合
            wnt = errorList.size();//エラー数
            mav.addObject("errorList",errorList);
            session.setAttribute("errorList", errorList);
        }
        if(importList!=null) {
            cnt = importList.size();//正常数
        }
        //インポートボタン　と　導出ボタンを分けるため設定の記録
        session.setAttribute("imported",true);
        mav.addObject("wnt",wnt);//エラー数
        mav.addObject("cnt",cnt);//正常数
        mav.setViewName("/retailExcelImport");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

### i'll explain my logic below.

### The excel upload will process and show us the successful imported data number and the error either , service puts the successList,errorList into map and return to controller then count the size of them .Then i could export and reedit the error data and do this process again until it's done.

Now i want to write the junit test of this .But i can't find the similar sample of excel upload test , help me please ,thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could create a `MockMultiPartFile` and pass it to your method under test:

```
MultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("filename", "someTestFile.xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel", new ClassPathResource("someTestFile.xls").getInputStream());
```

Where `someTestFile.xls` is a file in your `test/resources` folder. The argument `"filename"` should be the same as the value used in the @RequestParam;  `@RequestParam(value = "filename")`

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to automate the upload of the excel file. Assume your browser is working as expected. But you have to test the processing of the data.

In your testcase you have to:

1. Prepare some test data: create `MultipartFile testDataFile`, `ModelAndView testDataMav`
2. Create call the method `excelImport(testDataFile, testDataMav)`
3. Compare the return value with the value you are expecting